# Textarea scrollbar overlapping round border in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea, scrollbar

For some reason, when round border is added to the textarea, in IE the scrollbar slightly overlaps the border corners.
See https://jsfiddle.net/bgas48b4/ (in IE)

```
<style>
textarea{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 4px;
 height: 100px;
}
</style>

<textarea></textarea>
```

My temporary solution was to use `overflow-y:auto` to hide the scrollbar by default.

However, I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it is better for look and feel in IE

```
 textarea{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow:hidden;
        max-height:150px;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: thats the solution i am currently using - the scrollbar is initially hidden. But when the text area content exceeds the textarea height the scrollbar appears and  the problem is visible again.

Comment: yes it is browser behavier. but page first look is fine.