# Border radius are cutting by textarea with scrollbars (IE11)

Tags: html

The right corner borders are cutting by a textarea that has a scrollbar. It only happens in IE11, other browsers are working fine.

This is the **CSS**:

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgas48b4/) and this

[image]

Comment: For future reference, it would be handy to know which version of IE you are using!

Comment: Take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191515/textarea-scrollbar-overlapping-round-border-in-ie

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought that some padding would fix it. Something like:

```
textarea{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

It looks fine to me in Chrome. I would test it in IE, but I'm on a Macbook.

Comment: I don't think this will work because the padding creates space inside the textarea and the problem is related to the scrollbar. It hasn't rounded corners.